# show local weather using openweathermap api

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I am going to make a web app that show local weather using openweathermap api.
When I click the button, an IP API was called to get the co-ordinate of my location(longitude and latitude). These information then was used with API key (I registered in the website openweathermap.org) to create URL to call weather info according to the APIdocs, then change the HTML element with the data got from the server. I doing this  [on codepen](http://codepen.io/datvimaru50/pen/EKmgRB). I tried to do the simplest one but it doesn't work.

```
<h1>weather forcast</h1>
<button id="btn">view</button>
<p id ="test">change me</p>
<p id ="place">place</p>
<p id ="temp">temperature</p>
<p id ="description">description</p>
```

```js
var getLocation = function(data) {
    var lat = data.lat;
    var lon = data.lon;
    var apiKey = "[APIKEY]";
};

var url =  'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?' + 'lat=' + lat     + '&lon=' + lon + '&appid=' + apiKey;
//call back function to extract weather info.
var getWeather = function(data) {
    var temp = data.main.temp;
    var description = data.weather[0].description;
    var place = data.name;
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        $.getJSON('http://ip-api.com/json', getLocation, 'jsonp')
        $.getJSON(url, getWeather, 'jsonp');
        $("#test").text("I AM CHANGED. THANKS!")
        $("#temp").text(temp)
        $("#description").text(description)
        $("#place").text(place)
    })
})
```

Comment: You must not use the API KEY in JS. That's for server side only

Comment: And in browers like Firefox, the code won't work anyway as a URL from another site is blocked for AJAX

Comment: @devaldcool: must not use API KEY in JS, here I use and It worked. What do you really mean?

Comment: API KEY is a secret key. Treat it like your password. Get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues. The first is that the `$.getJSON` calls are asynchronous, so the `text()` of the elements will be changed *before* any request completes. You need to place all code dependant on the values returned from the request in the callback functions.

Secondly you have issues with variable scope where you're defining your variables inside the function and then attempting to use them outside where they will be `undefined`.

With that said, you need to re-arrange your logic to something like this:

```
var getWeather = function(data) {
    $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather', {
        lat: data.lat,
        lon: data.lon,
        appid: "[APIKEY HERE]"
    }, showWeather, 'jsonp');
};

var showWeather = function(data) {
    $("#test").text("I AM CHANGED. THANKS!")
    $("#temp").text(data.main.temp)
    $("#description").text(data.weather[0].description)
    $("#place").text(data.name)
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        $.getJSON('http://ip-api.com/json', getWeather)
    })
})
```

Note that the function calls are chained from the event (ie the `click` makes the location AJAX request, which calls `getWeather` which then calls `showWeather`. Also note how the variables are now local and used within their own function scope.

Finally, check that you're using the correct data formats for the AJAX requests. `ip-api.com/json` is returning `JSON`, not `JSONP`.

Comment: @VirginieLGB: thanks, It worked but the 'place' does not show the right information of my location.

Comment: @DalesVu that's down to the ip-api.com result. Normally the best they can do is to scan your IP address and geolocate that, so I guess the location it's returning is where your nearest exchange/ISP server is.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: it return a completely strange place name, I don't know why, it is not the location where my nearest exchange/ISP is (because I know where). The first time I tried, it returned right info.

Answer (score 0):

***You can get data about the location with use third-party API. for example:http://ip-api.com/.**
You get your location weather data from OpenWeatherMap service using the ip-api. its help you to get visitor location weather.*

```
 var getIP = 'http://ip-api.com/json/';
    var openWeatherMap = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
    $.getJSON(getIP).done(function(location) {
        $.getJSON(openWeatherMap, {
            lat: location.lat,
            lon: location.lon,
            units: 'metric',
            APPID: 'Your-Openweather-Apikey'
        }).done(function(weather) {
          $('#weather').append(weather.main.temp);
            console.log(weather);
        })
    })
```