# Display local weather and time on a website

Tags: javascript, html, api, time, weather

I am a bit of a novice to programming and have started to dive into JavaScript lately. I am trying to create a small widget on a website I am helping a friend build. I want to build a widget on the website that displays the current local time for the user browsing, but also his location and the weather at his or her location.

So far, I have managed to create the script to display the local time for the user, but what I cannot figure out is the weather app.

My idea is to request the IP address from the client and link that to a geo location and lastly a weather API. Again, I am quite a novice in this field so any help would be appreciated. Feels like I have been Googling without any success for the last two days.

So far, I have the following code for the local time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:24px;
}   
  
</style>
<script>
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
  h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">
<table>
<tr><td>Current Local Time:</td><td><div id="txt"</div></tr><td></td>
</div>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show local weather using openweathermap api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174177/show-local-weather-using-openweathermap-api)

Answer (score 0):

thats a great project for learning javascript. The more experienced you get with javascript the more you will learn about the different api features of the browser. One of these features is the navigator to ask the user for permission for geolocation and to retrieve the data:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( (data) => console.log(data) )
```

The following link gives you a great and more detailed Overview about Geolocation possibilities of the browser -> [html geolocation](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

You can now send these values to a backend which maps from geolocation to weahterinformation.

Answer (score 0):

first try to get user's location

now you need to use an api and filter by that location
to do that there is many ways that can help depending on the Api here is some suggestion you will find

some apis uses longitude and latitude and others uses location name.

so in this example you will get the latitude and longitude of user location and then use them like the following in a fetch method that is GET Method by default .

```
<script>
    const getlocation = () => {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(async(pos) => {
            var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
            var long = pos.coords.longitude;
            const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + long;
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const data = await response.json();
            
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
</script>
```

the data will be in json
so you can jump into any necessary variables in json object and get it for example
if you get

```
{
  "coord": { "lon": 139,"lat": 35},
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01n"
    }
  ],......
```

you can create a variable and get weather by doing this

```
const result = data.weather[0];
var id = result.id
```

Note the URL not working and you need to have a valid API key or use another one if you have.